# What is the syntax for accessing PHP object properties?

Tags: php, oop, properties, getter-setter

**How do you access a PHP object's properties?**

Also, what is the difference between accessing an object's property with
`$this->$property1` vs. `$this->property1`?

When I try to use `$this->$property1` I get the following error:

> 'PHP: Cannot access empty property'.

PHP's [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php) on object properties has one comment which mentions this, but the comment doesn't really explain in depth.

Comment: Take this manual page instead and look for "variable property names" section: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php (the first part might be interesting for you, too) (found on the page you linked in your answer, you should more carefully read the docs)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

1. `$property1` // specific variable
2. `$this->property1` // specific attribute

The general use on classes is without `"$"` otherwise you are calling a variable called `$property1` that could take any value.

Example:

```php
class X {
  public $property1 = 'Value 1';
  public $property2 = 'Value 2';
}
$property1 = 'property2';  //Name of attribute 2
$x_object = new X();
echo $x_object->property1; //Return 'Value 1'
echo $x_object->$property1; //Return 'Value 2'
```

Comment: And if the property has a space, like ˋprop nr 1ˋ?

Comment: not understand why echo $x_object->$property1; return 'Value 2' but not 'property2'...

Answer (score 18):

`$this->property1` means:

use the object and get the variable property1 bound to this object

`$this->$property1` means:

evaluate the string $property1 and use the result to get the variable named by $property1 result bound to this object

Comment: @hakra links to manuals are generally not considered answers, as those links tend to change... however, I would agree that a citation and/or a link to the source would be a nicer variant for an answer

Answer (score 3):

`property1` is a string while `$property1` is a variable. So when accessing `$this->$property1` PHP looks for contents of the variable named `$property1` and because it (probably) doesn't exist it's empty so that's why you get the `Cannot access empty property` error.